# Next i18next Production Redirection Bug

Tags: next.js, i18next

I have a strange bug with Next i18Next just in production. Here are some images that can describe better the issue.

[Here on localhost, the home page link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvWwR.png)

[And then on search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKAcl.png)

[Here on production, home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaIuo.png)

[And then the search page on production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7K1V.png)

i18n.js

```
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default;
const { localeSubpaths } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
  otherLanguages: ['fr_BE', 'nl_BE'],
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  ns: ['common'],
  defaultNS: 'common',
  strictMode: false,
  browserLanguageDetection: false,
  serverLanguageDetection: false,
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/static/locales'),
  localeSubpaths
});
```

next.config.js

```
const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require('next-i18next/rewrites');

const localeSubpaths = {
  en: 'en',
  fr_BE: 'fr_BE',
  nl_BE: 'nl_BE'
};

module.exports = {
  // experimental: {
  //   reactMode: 'concurrent'
  // },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths
  },
  rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths)
};
```

Thank you all for your attention and your help.